# Proper formatting of file URI in file protocol

Tags: windows, macos, file, uri, protocols

So i'm trying to figure out the proper amount of slashes to use when using grabbing files on different systems.

I know the proper format is `file://hostname/path`
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Format).

Since i am only working with files localhost the host is omitted but the slash separating the hostname from the rest of the path remains which gives me 
`file:///[path]` which is all good and well and is easy to find examples of.

However when using the same software on a OSX machine i don't know how to properly format the URI, as I understand a slash denotes the root
(http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/paths.html)
which would make the proper format:

`file://localhost//[path from root]`

omitting the hostname gives me
`file:////[path from root]`
which i can not for the life of me find any example of, even though I can easily find examples of people using three shlashes in a mac environment (which should be incorrect?).

In my case both solutions seem to work but that is probably due to the fact that the 'incorrect' one is being changed without my knowledge into a correct one, and I can not trust that to happen everywhere else.
So please, someone exaplain this to me, which one is correct?

If the question is not good or belongs somewhere else please infrom me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're asking whether or not you need the first '/' character in the URL is required. The answer can be found in section [3.10 of RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738):

> The file URL scheme is used to designate files accessible on a
> particular host computer. This scheme, unlike most other URL schemes,
> does not designate a resource that is universally accessible over the
> Internet.
>
> A file URL takes the form:
>
> ```
>    file://<host>/<path>
> ```
>
> where <host> is the fully qualified domain name of the system on
> which the <path> is accessible, and <path> is a hierarchical
> directory path of the form <directory>/<directory>/.../<name>.
>
> For example, a VMS file
>
> ```
>  DISK$USER:[MY.NOTES]NOTE123456.TXT
> ```
>
> might become
>
> ```
>  <URL:file://vms.host.edu/disk$user/my/notes/note12345.txt>
> ```
>
> As a special case, <host> can be the string "localhost" or the
> empty    string; this is interpreted as `the machine from which the
> URL is    being interpreted'.
>
> The file URL scheme is unusual in that it does not specify an
> Internet protocol or access method for such files; as such, its
> utility in network protocols between hosts is limited.

The file URL scheme works in the same way as all of the network urls. Host specification is dealt with in another RFC. The VMS example uses a disk/user specifier which is non-standard. However, in most OSes (windows, unix, machos) some of the parameters are *implicit*, and are therefore the empty string:

A fully-qualified file url looks like this:

file://user:password@host/path/to/file

Both user, password and host are generally implicit to the currently logged in user and the localhost (unless the filesystem allows user specified permissions in the URL). Everything after the protocol specifier (file://) is *relative* to the (specified or implicit) user on the (current or specified) host. If you strip away the protocol, user and host info from the URL, you are left with a standard (unix) path. Given what you know about paths, you can treat them in the same way (and rightfully assume that your OS will do the same):

1. Paths with a preceding slash are **absolute** paths *from the mounted root directory* for the user/host, basically the highest level in the filesystem hierarchy visible to the program running as the current user on the current host:  `/path/to/file`
2. Paths without a preceding slash are **relative** paths from the **program's** *current working directory*. `path/to/file`

So, your file URLs should be specified in the same way that you would specify paths in your program or shell script:

Absolute: `file:///path/to/file`
Relative: `file://path/to/file`

In practice, it is always wise to either convert all paths to absolute paths at runtime by using an *absolute* defined base directory and appending a relative path before converting to a URL. It is not recommended that file URLs be passed between machines, or used on network mounted file systems where directories may change, or may be mounted to dynamic locations (using automount for example). They should only be used for user-defined locations, or well known cross-host filesystem locations.

Comment: There is a draft RFC which explicitly lays out the algorithm for turning paths into file URLs, which is compatible with the above statements, especially my final comment about converting all paths to absolute: [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-file-scheme-03) https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-file-scheme-03

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Didn't realize that the <host> were interpreted as tags when I copy pasted from the rfc.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation.